# Flag Comment as inappropriate button plugin

Tags: plugins, comments

Is there a good plugin to provide a "*Flag comment as inappropriate*" button to comments in my posts? All I've seem were last updated in 2009 or so...

Answer (score 2):

You can try out other comment systems like Disqus or Livefyre. They have the flag as inappropriate feature built into them. Not to mention these commenting systems are real-time.